# Accesing statistics of a single Marketing Email with Sendgrid API

Tags: analytics, sendgrid, mass-emails

I have been looking through the documentation for both the [General Statistics](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/index.html) and [Advanced Statistics](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/statistics_advanced.html) - but it seems only aggregated statistics are available. From what I am able to find, the most detailed information is available for a single day within a single category. But is it possible to retrieve statistics for a single marketing email, using e.g. it's name as parameter? Or is it necessary to use the Event Webhook, to store all events (opens, clicks, etc.) in my end, and do all the calculations myself?

Thank you

brgds
Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, it's necessary to use the Event Webhook. Using Event Webhook also allows you to implement [unique_args](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html), for more detailed & granular stats. You can use as many args per message as you'd like, naming the keys and values to whatever makes sense for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However from what I see, unique_args are only available in SMPT API and not in Marketing Emails API? How can we implement them using the latter?

Comment: Correct, they can not be used in the Marketing Email Platform. I didn't realize you were using that interface. There's not Stats API for the current general of Marketing Emails, though I think there will be on the new one, in a few months.